# python pdf библиотеки не импортируются под apache 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache2, pdf, wsgi

Пытаюсь произвести хоть какой-то рендер pdf из html на django сервере под управлением apache 2.4, но при попытке произвести import , сервер выдает 500 и **ImportError: No module named 'pdfbox'**. Пробовал django-easy-pdf, pdfkit и другие
Сервер : **apache 2.4**, **ubuntu 16.04**, **python 3.5**

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй weasyprint

```
from weasyprint import HTML
pages_pdf = HTML(string=pages_html).render()
```